# multitasking view problem after suspend

Tags: display, nvidia, suspend, multitasking-view

I installed elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki couple of days ago and everything seems to run fine except this strange problem:

[image]

The background of multitasking view looks corrupted almost every time after resuming the system from suspend and sometimes the wallpaper also looks the same way. I have Nvidia GTX 660 and the latest driver (nvidia-375) installed from the AppCenter.

Comment: Did you have the same problems before installing the driver? Did the system work properly without the driver? Maybe it would be worth just trying it without it.

Comment: I'm also wondering the same as Eric G. Nvidia drivers tend to be pretty solid, but they are not without their common quirks. I've experienced some wacky issues with my Nvidia GTX 710 with several driver releases, but they're usually fixed by the subsequent update.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me, Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050, using the latest 384.98 Nvidia Driver.

The problem disappears if I switch the driver to use the "Power Saving Mode" which disables the Nvidia GPU and uses the Intel one instead - the return from suspend is much faster and there are no visual defects like the ones on the picture above.

It looks like a problem with the driver.